# "They move everywhere sell their goods" or "selling their goods"?

Tags: word-choice, present-participles

> - They move everywhere **sell** their goods without caring about the weather
> - They move everywhere **selling** their goods without caring about the weather

Which one is correct?

Comment: You could repair the first version by inserting the word "to": *They move everywhere **to sell** their goods without caring about the weather.*

Answer (score 2):

The following sentence is correct.

They move everywhere selling their goods without caring about the weather.

Answer (score 2):

I would pick the second of the two, but add a comma before the participle clause:

> They move everywhere, selling their goods without caring about the weather.
>   Or:
>   They move everywhere, selling their goods *in any weather* (*regardless of weather conditions*).

One may also mend a bit the first one, adding the conjunction **and**:

> They move everywhere **and** sell their goods without caring about the weather.

The meaning will be a bit different though. In the first sentence, the second clause describes  the manner in which they **move**. In the second, the second clause is more "independent".

Comment: Why the downvote?